# fread is not reading other file formats

Tags: c, fread

I am fairly new to C still, but the program below compiles just fine, (using gcc) and it even works when using text files, but I when I use other file formats, i.e. `png`, I get nothing. The console spits out `?PNG` and nothing else. I don't want the image to print as an image, obviously the program does nothing like that, but I would like the data from the png file to be printed. Why is the program not fread-ing properly? Is is because fread refuses any file other than text?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fp;

int main() {
    char buffer[1000];

    fp=fopen("FILE IN QUESTION HERE", "rb");
    if(fp==NULL) {
        perror("An error occured while opening the file...");
        exit(1);
    }
    fread(buffer, 1000, 1, fp);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read a C book. `fread` does not interpret the data read.

Comment: Is your `fread()` *really* not working well? Did you check it using debugger?

Comment: I fully intend to read a C book, at some point, and I know my question is silly, but I'm just too excited to begin coding with C. :)

Comment: Side note: please checkout [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on META site...

Answer (score 4):

`%s` in `printf()` is for printing null-terminated string, not binary data and PNG header contains a signature to prevent the data from being transfered as text by mistake.

(Actually there are no `0x00` in the PNG signature and `printf()` stopped at the `0x00` contained in the size of `IHDR` chunk)

Use `fwrite()` to output binary data, or print the bytes one-by-one via `putchar()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fp; /* avoid using gloval variables unless it is necessary */
    char buffer[1000] = {0}; /* initialize to avoid undefined behavior */

    fp=fopen("FILE IN QUESTION HERE", "rb");
    if(fp==NULL) {
        perror("An error occured while opening the file...");
        exit(1);
    }
    fread(buffer, 1000, 1, fp);
    fwrite(buffer, 1000, 1, stdout); /* use fwrite instead of printf */
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> fread is not reading other file formats

Code does not check the result of `fread()`.  **That** is the way to determine if `fread()` is working.

```
char buffer[1000];
// fread(buffer, 1000, 1, fp);
size_t sz = fread(buffer, 1000, 1, fp);
if (sz == 0) puts("Did not read an entire block");
```

`fread()` returns the number of blocks read.  With OP's case, code is attempting to read one 1000 byte block.  Recommend reading 1000 blocks, each of 1 `char` rather than 1 block of a 1000 `char`.  Further, avoid magic numbers.

```
for (;;) {
  size_t sz = fread(buffer, sizeof buffer[0], sizeof buffer, fp);
  if (sz == 0) break;

  // Somehow print the buffer.
  print_it(buffer, sz);
}
```

OP call to `printf()` expects a pointer to a string.  A C *string* is an array of characters up to and including the terminating null character.  `buffer` may/may not contain a null character and useful data after a null character.

```
// Does not work for OP
// printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

The data of a .png file is mostly binary and will have little textual meaning. A sample print function of mixed binary data and text follows.  Most output will appears meaningless until one learns the .png file format.  Untested code.

```
int print_it(const unsigned char *x, size_t sz) {
  char buf[5];
  unsigned column = 0;
  while (sz > 0) {
    sz--;
    if (isgraph(*x) && *x != `(`) {
      sprintf(buf, "%c", *x);
    } else {
      sprintf(buf, "(%02X)", *x);
    }
    column += strlen(buf);
    if (column > 80) {
      column = 0;
      fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
    fputs(buf, stdout);
  }
  if (column > 0)  fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```